# Does haskell support unicode combining characters?

Tags: haskell, unicode, combining-marks

I've looked at the lexical specification of haskell, and I can use a lower case unicode character is a valid variable name.

I believe it not however legal to use modifiers with lowercase letters? Attempts so far suggest not. This stackoverflow post also suggests this is a none starter: [Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24941921/whats-wrong-with-this-haskell-unicode-variable-name/)

I assume this was thoughtfully thrashed out when unicode was supported in Haskell. Can anyone suggest why not? Is it a terrible idea, or something no-one has got round to?